# Disable Text Selection highlighting in Fancytree Mutliselect Mode

Tags: fancytree

I have to allow multi-select in Fancytree with SHIFT and Mouse Click combination.

Here, how to avoid the default text selection when using the SHIFT key.

I have tried applying the required styles as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) and it is not working.

Is there any other way to resolve this in Fancytree control with selection mode 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text selection Issue is resolved by using  document.selection.clear()  in select event.

Comment: if (document.selection) {
            document.selection.empty();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }